# Convert onclick to onmouseover

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

Can someone explain how to convert the following code to onmouseover instead of on click?

```
<button type="button" onclick="_stopScroll = !_stopScroll;">Toggle Scroll</button>
var _stopScroll = false;
window.onload = function(event) {
    document.onscroll = function(ev) {
        if (_stopScroll) {
            document.body.scrollTop = "1000px";
        }
    }
};
```

I need the code to execute upon dragging the mouse over the button, and when mouse leaves, to reset to scroll.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can stop the scroll on mouseenter and reset the flag on mouse leave

```
<button type="button" onmouseenter="_stopScroll = true;"  onmouseleave="_stopScroll = false;">Toggle Scroll</button>
```

---

Since you have jQuery, use a jQuery event handler instead of inline one

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.scroll-stop').hover(function() {
    _stopScroll = true;
  }, function() {
    _stopScroll = false;
  });
  document.on('scroll', function(ev) {
    if (_stopScroll) {
      document.body.scrollTop = "1000px";
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<button type="button" class="scroll-stop">Toggle Scroll</button>
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to include the following line in the org code:

Comment: `var dist = $(document.body).scrollTop();`

Comment: and "1000px" would be dist

Comment: with this in mind, where would I place the var def, to achieve a constant effect? In other words where should it be placed, so that everytime time mouse goes in/out the var would be updated, to make the scroll stuck at given dist?

Comment: place it inside the `if` condition

Comment: It works with "1000px", but when i place the var in the if cond it doesnt work :(

Answer (score 0):

replace onclick with onmouseover

```html
<button type="button" onmouseover="_stopScroll = !_stopScroll;">Toggle Scroll</button>
var _stopScroll = false;
window.onload = function(event) {
    document.onscroll = function(ev) {
        if (_stopScroll) {
            document.body.scrollTop = "1000px";
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: How would I then go about the mouseleave?

Comment: use onmouseleave instead of onmouseover like same and do what you want to

Comment: Well yeah, but to achieve the opposite effect, so that I would be able to scroll normally on mouseleave